# Invalid scopes in google quickstart application

Tags: google-sheets, google-oauth

I have an application that serves to add slides from my PC into a google slides file, and it relies on the following code to check authorization:

```
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
```

and where the variable SCOPES is set as:

```
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
```

or - it does not change the outcome

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
```

and the credentials are :

```
{"installed":{"client_id":"162352680285-0i0fmpq50gqgsm1d796mmdim3c3oe874.apps.googleusercontent.com","project_id":"quickstart-1613196175693","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_secret":"REDACTED","redirect_uris":["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","http://localhost"]}}
```

The program runs into an exception

```
 raise exceptions.RefreshError(error_details, response_body)
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_scope: Some requested scopes were invalid.
```

This is surprising because the program ran error free till recently

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure whether this will solve it, but I posted an answer explaining an issue with your current code. I hope this is useful to you. If that's not the case, consider providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @LP0 please go to google cloud console and reset your client secret.  You just shared it with the internet.  It is against TOS to share your credentials with anyone you should keep them private.

Answer (score 2):

#### Issue:

`SCOPES` should be a list of scopes, not a string:

> **scopes (Sequence[str])**: The list of scopes to request during the flow.

#### Solution:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
```

#### Reference:

- [Flow.from_client_secrets_file](https://google-auth-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/google_auth_oauthlib/flow.html#Flow.from_client_secrets_file)